# Save URL of AJAX loaded page, so it can be loaded after a refresh

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

We have an application writted in PHP. Its main view is for example: `/pages/index`.

Now when the user clicks on certain links, it pulls in other Views via ajax. ie. a call may look like `/pages/publish`, so the PHP outputs the relevant html for the publish section back to the index view.

The problem we have is we'd like to be able to give the user the option of refreshing and seeing the same view as before. So, my initial thought is this, when we use `.load()` in jQuery, to take the URL its going to load and store it somewhere to be read by the PHP if the user refreshes. Is the best way to do or can someone think of a better way to do this whole thing?

Comment: You could save the URL in a session. However, why not use the hash for your ajax loaded pages. Something along the lines of `/pages/#index`, and `pages/#publish`.

Comment: Perhaps I don't understand something, but how the problem relates with the update of $_SERVER array?

Answer (score 2):

Check out [jQuery.address](http://www.asual.com/jquery/address) which should solve your problems! It allows AJAX loading of new pages, and will update the address bar accordingly. If a user saves this URL and reloads it, the script on the page can then load the correct page.

Alternatively, if you're HTML5-only, then you can try [history.pushState()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history) which will modify the URL without using the hash symbol, but support isn't 100% yet. (I don't think... it certainly behaves oddly on iPad from my experience.)

Comment: This solution doesn't involve any server-side stuff, so applies to PHP, ASP and the rest too.